# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesException

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to deploy a web application which I have imported from Eclipse workspace to NetBeans. But it's not getting deployed, instead it's giving me the below exception.

```
15 Jul, 2011 5:59:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.StreamingDestroyerListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesException
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig.<clinit>(MyfacesConfig.java:80)
        at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.StreamingDestroyerListener.contextInitialized(StreamingDestroyerListener.java:32)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:521)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        **at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)**
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        **at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)**
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
        **at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)**
```

Am I missing some JARs?

Answer (score 12):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class was present in the classpath during compiletime. Tomahawk has somewhere an `import javax.faces.FacesException;` line in the codebase. That is one of the classes of the core JSF API.

This means that the JSF libraries are missing in the webapp's classpath. The project was in Netbeans apparently associated with a server which is already bundled with JSF such as Glassfish, JBoss AS, etc. The project in Eclipse is seemingly not properly associated with the server, or the server in question does **not** have JSF bundled such as Tomcat, Jetty, etc.

The stacktrace hints that you're using Tomcat. You need to [download](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) JSF separately and drop the JAR files in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` (there where your Tomahawk libraries also are).

Comment: What, if I'm getting the same error in Jetty (while executing `mvn jetty:run`) ? I tried to put JSF jar into `WEB-INF/lib`, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Dmitri: Maven requires a different way of managing dependencies (heck, it **is** a way of managing dependencies). You'd need to configure it by `pom.xml`.

Comment: I know and I added the respective dependency into Jetty config section. The ClassNotFoundError has gone, but now I'm getting `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutcomeTargetButton`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, CNF exception always means missing JARs.  The class loader can't find this:

```
javax.faces.FacesException
```

You find it by cutting & pasting the class name into [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com), like this:

http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=javax.faces.FacesException

Answer (score 0):

To add a different experience: when I encountered this problem it was because I was using ICEFaces and had included the ICEFaces jars in Tomcat's `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` directory, but included `javax.faces.jar` in my webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory. The solution for me was to move `javax.faces.jar` from `/WEB-INF/lib` to `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`. Also, make sure you use the correct version of `javax.faces.jar` if you use something like ICEFaces.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this issue by removing provided scope from POM on `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl`, so Maven can now generate the both jars to Catalina starts up.